# VB.NET comparing times

Tags: vb.net

So I have two datetimepickers where the user will input a start time and an end time. I want to check that the end time is greater (after) the start time, but if i enter midnight (00:00), which is after start time, it will see it as being smaller than the start time. 
How can I get around this?

Lets say the start time is 21:00 and the end time is 00:00

```
 If start_time.value > end_time.value Then
            errors.Enqueue("End time must be later than Start time")
        End If
```

my code will say that the end time is before the start time.

Comment: Please add some sample data.

Comment: What makes you think that "midnight is after start time"?

Comment: use the date portion as well?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function for it.

```
If DateDiff(start_time.value, end_time.value, "s") > 0 Then
    errors.Enqueue("End time must be later than Start time")
End If
```